# window.setinterval function behaving differently in different browser engines

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, dom-events

I have written a function `window.setinterval` followed by two if conditions. Working absolutely as I wanted in Firefox, Opera, IE. In webkit engines, the function is not being carried forward.

```
 x = window.setInterval(function() {
            if(a.speed >= a.maxSpeed && b.speed >= b.maxSpeed && c.speed >= c.maxSpeed) {
                 a.stop();
                 b.stop();
                 c.stop();
            }
            if(a.speed === 0 && b.speed === 0 && c.speed === 0 && completed === 3) {
                window.clearInterval(x);
                enableControl();
                printResult();
                enableControl(); 
            }
        }, 100);
```

I've set an interval where when max.speeds are reached, stop function should be called and If speeds are 0, the result should be displayed. In Mozilla, IE, Opera its working exactly as I wanted. But in webkit, the first if condition itself isn't being executed. An infinite loop is running.

I've tried nested if also, even then the first if condition isn't being executed. Please help me resolve this issue.

If this isn't a correct approach, can I trigger a timeout after `c.stop()` and manually make the speed's of a,b,c to 0 and then enable control and display result?

This the stop function you asked for:

```
 Slot.prototype.stop =        function() {
    var _this = this,
        limit = 30;
    clearInterval(_this.si);
    _this.si = window.setInterval(function() {
        if(_this.speed > limit) {
            _this.speed -= _this.step;
            $(_this.el).spSpeed(_this.speed);
        }
        if(_this.speed <= limit) {
            _this.finalPos(_this.el);
            $(_this.el).spSpeed(0);
            $(_this.el).spStop();
            clearInterval(_this.si);
            $(_this.el).removeClass('motion');
            _this.speed = 0;
        }
    }, 100);
};
```

Comment: Is speed a Floating point? And if yes how is speed changed to become 0?

Comment: any errors? you don't show what a,b,c are either so we can't really help out there.

Comment: @t.niese No,Its not a floating point.

Comment: @Kennypu I have given the function code for stop in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'll excuse an answer that kind of sidesteps your question, there are arguments that you should really not be using `setInterval` anyway (see [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2009/05/14/setinterval-is-moderately-evil.aspx) and [this](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#other.timeouts)).  The strength of the guarantee regarding the time interval is OS and browser dependent, and therefore not very strong.  You're better off using `setTimeout` to schedule a function that reschedules itself using `setTimeout` when necessary.  If you're worried about the exactness of the interval, you can always adjust the time interval to real time as you see fit.

Comment: Thank you. But I want that function to run repeatedly after a stipulated duration. In that case, setTimeout doesnot come handy.

Comment: But it does.  It's just a slightly different way of thinking about things.  For repeated tasks and you can use ``setInterval`` and they will run unless you use ``clearInterval`` (as you know).  ``setTimeout`` can be looked at as the same thing, except that you have to explicitly reschedule the tasks, i.e. they run repeatedly only if you call ``setTimeout`` again *within* the function you passed to ``setTimeout``.  ``var task; task = function () { finished = repeatingLogic(); if (!finished) setTimeout(task, delay);}; task();``

Comment: The only real meaningful differences are that repeating the task is explicit now, and that the delay is ``delay`` + the probably negligible execution time of the code, which you can compensate for, if it's really important to you.